# Is saying bye to only certain coworkers rude?

Tags: colleagues

When leaving for the day going down the row of cubical, I only say bye to some people as I pass them.  I clearly see everyone but for some people I don't say anything as I pass.  Is that rude behavior and excluding people or is this okay and just based on what I want to do?

The people I don't say anything to would also clearly notice that I said bye to some people and not them if they are not working on something immersive.

Comment: It might.  Are there any particular reason you do this?

Comment: Is there any method to your exclusion? For example saying "bye" only to the people that need to know whether you are still in the office? Or is it just not saying "bye" to Alice, because you don't like her?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen some reason is they don't say bye to me, other maybe I don't really like them as much but I wouldn't say I dislike them either.

Comment: @pia it takes two to tango.  Consider how you would like it to be, and then consider what you can do to make it happen.

Comment: I would be careful to say "**Bye**" to people if they are working hard or if their coworkers in the next cubicle are working and need focus because your word "**Bye**" to a number of people in a row of cubicle may interrupt their work, their train of thought, or conversation on the phone with someone else.

Comment: What do other people do when they leave? How would this question change if you didn't say "bye" to anyone? Start with the premise that you don't have to say anything when you leave and ask what would help the office.

Comment: It seems to be a back and forth thing. If I would get offended when person X leaves and doesn't say bye I put that person on the mental list of people to say bye to

Comment: In which culture? Country and company and site conventions on this may all vary.

Answer (score 9):

Depends on the size of the office, often it makes more sense just to call out on the way to the door, and anyone who wants to reply will. No one is left out.

Pointedly leaving people out can be construed by some as insulting. But just passing them by should be fine. Most people have particular colleagues they interact with on a more friendly basis.

Personally I just be polite with the greetings and goodbyes to everyone including a few I wouldn't pee on if they were on fire. It costs nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Some research has been done into when and in what circumstances one must acknowledge the presence of another person. If they look you in the eye, you have to do something. If they look towards you, you usually have to. If you come within about 3 meters, unless it is a busy sidewalk or they are heads-down, you have to.

It really has nothing to do with your preference, this is wired primate behavior. Going against the trend will probably be harder than going along with it. That said, you don't have to run with it either, just do what your instincts say and forget about it.

In short, if they are heads-down, you probably get a pass. You don't have to interrupt people to be polite to them.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on the Office Culture and the regional culture.

I would see nothing bad of leaving and saying bye to the people who routinely work with who were on my way to the exit. I wouldn't take stopping to say goodbye to everyone as a sign of rudeness.

But then, I work in IT.

There are some caveats - say someone I don't particularly work with happened to be leaving at the same time as me, we hop in the elevator and as we go our separate ways - a bye or a see you tomorrow would probably be what courtesy dictates.

Where I think the line of rude is - is if you deliberately ignore someone - so for example, you are walking past, they turn to catch your eye as you are heading - then blowing past them as if they weren't there is probably rude.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that rude behavior and excluding people

It would be rude in companies/cultures where I worked.